# wxWidgets - Sizer disable auto layout

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Quite new to wxWidgets and ran into an issue with sizers, in my program I got quite a few buttons in a custom panel which I would like to add a horizontal scrollbar too. However the different sizers that I've tried all got auto layout which re-arranges my buttons upon start and change the distance between them while resizing, I would like to disable all of this behaviour but can't find any documentation on how to do so. Is it not possible or have I just been going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

If you use sizers, you should let them manage the layout, of course.

You *can* use absolute positions if you really want to, but this is strongly not recommended and will not allow you to create the layouts that work in all configurations. But if you do decide to do this (again, you really shouldn't), then you wouldn't be using sizers at all.

Comment: Vadim IIUC, he wants the distance between 2 tables to stay constant, not that the layout is messes up. And if I remember correctly, this is possible.

Comment: Hmm, how well do sizers work with drawing objects in the same panel?

Comment: They're orthogonal, I don't understand how do you expect them to work together?

Comment: @VZ I didn't exactly which is why I figured disabling sizers is the next best thing.

Comment: It really isn't the best thing, sizers just help you to ensure that your child windows are positioned correctly independently of current resolution, font size, string length (think translations) etc. They don't change anything for drawing.